# How to toggle a secondary class using 'this' jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I want only the current '.image-content' class thats being hovered to toggle 'hover' class.

I know of the 'this' jquery selector but don't know how to implement it correctly in this situation

```
$('.image-content').hover(function() {
  $('.image-content-overlay').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

I want 'this' .image-content hover to toggle the class on .image-content-overlay

HTML

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <div class="image-content">
    <div class="image-content-overlay"></div>
        <img class="content-image" src="Events_Racquet.jpg">
        <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
        <div class="content-title">Racquet by Racquet Club</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML? Taking a wild guess, May be you need `$(this).find('.image-content-overlay')`

Comment: HTML has been added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the `.image-content-overlay` that's inside the `.image-content` that you've hovered to be toggled you can use `this` like this:

```
$('.image-content').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.image-content-overlay').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: I want 'this' .image-content hover to toggle the class on .image-content-overlay

Comment: @glittergirl If that answered your question will you please accept?

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to for the first 10min!